# 'Order by' ignored in LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a list by company name. I have tried the following code but this sorts the list by CompID and not CoShort. How should I change this to sort by CoShort?

```
Public Shared Function [SelectCompanyData](iElement() As Integer) As List(Of CompanyList)

    Dim db As New EntryDataContext()

    Dim q As IQueryable(Of CompanyList) = (From Act_Sub_Manfu_Link In db.Act_Sub_Manfu_Links _
            Join Company In db.Companies _
            On Act_Sub_Manfu_Link.CompID Equals Company.CompID _
            Where iElement.Contains(Act_Sub_Manfu_Link.ACCN) _
            And Company.In_Dir _
            Select New CompanyList With { _
                .CompID = Company.CompID, _
                .InDir = Company.In_Dir, _
                .CoShort = Company.CoShort _
                }).Distinct

    q.OrderBy(Function(c) c.CoShort)

    Dim list As List(Of CompanyList) = q.ToList

    Return list

End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to assign ordered collection into a variable:

```
Dim oq As IOrderedQueryable(Of CompanyList) = q.OrderBy(Function(c) c.CoShort)
```

And use it to get List of results:

```
Dim list As List(Of CompanyList) = oq.ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't need to be assigned to anything but the return value

```
Public Function SelectCompanyData(iElement() As Integer) As List(Of CompanyList)
    Dim db As New EntryDataContext()
    Return (From Act_Sub_Manfu_Link In db.Act_Sub_Manfu_Links _
            Join Company In db.Companies _
            On Act_Sub_Manfu_Link.CompID Equals Company.CompID _
            Where iElement.Contains(Act_Sub_Manfu_Link.ACCN) _
            And Company.In_Dir _
            Select New CompanyList With { _
                .CompID = Company.CompID, _
                .InDir = Company.In_Dir, _
                .CoShort = Company.CoShort _
                }).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(c) c.CoShort).ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. First of all I tried putting the orderby after the where clause but that didn't work. Is that because I have to have the orderby after the distinct?

Comment: Do you mean you had `Order By Company.CoShort` after the `Where` clause? Having the `OrderBy` after `Distinct` should not matter

Comment: Yes I had Order By Company.CoShort between the Where and the Select but doing that the list just sorted by CompID. Btw how do you get Where etc. to appear in grey?

Comment: You should be able to interchange and mix these LINQ and IEnumerable extension methods so it's not clear to me why it doesn't work. Maybe you had duplicate c.CoShort which were arbitrarily sorted before taking Distinct.